# Changing the background color of an EditText issue

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a simple layout with an edittext.

When I set the background of the `EditText` to a color

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

Then a strange thing happens when the edittext gains focus, the background color of the layout changes(!).

I need to change the background color dynamically, and I have the same result after calling:

```
subject.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(mycolor));
```

I have also tried the following method :

```
subject.setBackground(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor(mycolor)));
```

The result was the same.

Basically I want to change the background color of an Edittext in runtime.

Comment: @ASP I want to change the color dynamically, since I get the color from a remote server.

Comment: @ASP The color is not located in the resources.

Comment: do u get the color as a string or hex color code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was adding a parent layout to hold the background and set the `EditText` background to null.

I don't like that solution, but it works.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"  >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one::

```
 String myHexColor = "#CC2233";// color u get from webserver
EditText myView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
myView.setBackGroundColor(Color.pasrsehexString(myHexColor));
```

Comment: the method pasrsehexString(String) is undefined for the type Color, parseColor is what I use and it actually works.

Comment: i think this works:: myView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#636161"));